# Simple audio/mp3 player for small files

Tags: mp3, music-player, media

I have a new voicemail system that attaches mp3s to emails and sends them to me.  I'm using Thunderbird for IMAP email.

When I try to open them with Rythmbox, I run into trouble because of the playlist.  If I have music on pause, it won't even open the voicemail clip, it just starts playing the paused music.

I'm looking for a second player that loads fast to play these voicemails.  No other features are necessary. I'm guessing there may be an issue with the temporary file location.

Answer (score 3):

A simple little audio player called `decibel` is a python program that is incredibly fast and powerful. You do **not** need to import all your mp3s or other tracks before you can play them. With the full view selected from the view menu, it gives you a directory tree in the the sidebar (see the screenshot). You can expand the folder you want and either select that entire folder or just one or two tracks and then drag and drop into the main window pain (again see the screenshot). By default it is set to show just the home folder in the sidebar, but that can be changed: on the menu, go to edit > preferences > explorer and double click on file explorer.

If you go to edit > preferences there are a number of useful plugins that you can enable and you can also switch on some desktop integration features. There is also an equalizer available as well which has various presets. Again, you can keep it as a minimal player or use these other features; it is very configurable.

It is available in the repositories and more information can be found at [the official site](http://decibel.silent-blade.org/). Compared to certain other music players, which tend to be somewhat sluggish, `decibel` is great and loads in seconds.

If you open `Thunderbird` and go to edit > preferences > attachments you can set `decibel` as the default program to open mp3 attachments.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should help you decide.

[Fast Lightweight music players.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/omg-5-five-lightweight-music-players)

Comment: I like deadbeef. Also there a comman-line players which are very low profile.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a CLI mp3 player like mpg123 or mplayer or do you need a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can play almost any music file from the command line or a script using mpg321.  If you only specify a single file, it will play that file without loading a GUI and then quit.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mpg321/