# What music player for Ubuntu is *most* like Cog?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, music-player, media

[Cog](http://cogx.org/) is, far and away, my favourite music player. File browser on the left panel, pull a folder into the right panel, it plays the files you pull into the main box. Simple! Easy! Nice! Especially since I store all my music on my non-primary drive. Cog doesn't care where I keep my music! It just deals with whatever folder I tell it to monitor.

I also have about 200 gigs of music. It's a problem, I know.

I can't find a player this simple and elegant in Ubuntu.

Amarok: doesn't handle non-primary drives very well.
 
Banshee: kinda good, but fussy browsing/playlist systems.
 
Audacious: no file browser; it also crashes whenever I try to "import" all my music.

All I want -- seriously -- is something where I can look at my MP3 folder, drag a folder onto a playlist, and have that playlist play the songs.

Comment: Decibel is what you want- it's a great simple player: see my post here http://askubuntu.com/questions/176615/176626#176626

Comment: Yes but I didn't want to duplicate my post from that other answer as the explanation would be very similar.

Comment: Mik, you are the wind beneath my wings. Decibel is *exactly* what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try BeatBox.

> BeatBox is an easy to use, stable, fast and good looking music library
>   organizer written in vala.
>
> It has many modern features including Last.FM integration, (smart)
>   playlists, podcasts, Internet radio, similar songs playlist, simple
>   UI, instant search, queue system, mass song editing, advanced
>   equalizer and more.<sup>1</sup>

To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sgringwe/beatbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install beatbox
```

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Vibes](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/08/beatbox-music-player-06-released.html)</sup>

Comment: Decibel actually fits my needs even better, but BeatBox is a good suggestion. Thanks, Mitch!